# Binding assemblies works on one PC and doesn't work on another

Tags: c#, .net, fusion

I have a curios situation: we were experimenting in partially updating our application and found out that it worked on all PCs except one. So we have a deployment with several assemblies, each has it's version defined. Let's say they were `v1` Then we updated only part of them to `v2`.

There exists assembly `A` of version `v1` that is used in the deployment and it requires another assembly `B` which is now `v2`, but `A` still requires for `B` to be `v1`. We do not have any binding redirects applicable to this situation (we have some, but their `oldVersion` is bigger than `v1`)

Strangely that worked on all PCs except one. I'd expect it work on either, or on all. So my question - how this is possible and what is the difference?

I'm not searching for an answer on how to solve the issue - it is obvious, we need to either update our deployment fully, or use proper binding redirects. I'm more interested in understanding how this could happen, and to know what caused a different behavior for this single machine.

Comment: Is it possible that the .NET framework version on the 'doesn't work' machine is different from one on the the 'works well' machines?

Comment: @Codor Unfortunately I have no longer access to the machine, so I cannot check directly. But I have logs from it, and I see `mscorlib V=4.0.0.0` specified there, - this is the one we use here as well

Comment: @Codor but it might have been x86, when we use x64. But still it doesn't look to me like this could have had any impact